# How to ignore the commas inside sentence while reading csv file with python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file and I'd like to read it with pandas library in Python.

Here is the header and first line of my file.

```
content,topic,class,NRC-Affect-Intensity-anger_Score,NRC-Affect-Intensity-fear_Score,NRC-Affect-Intensity-sadness_Score,NRC-Affect-Intensity-joy_Score
'@stellargirl I loooooooovvvvvveee my Kindle2. Not that the DX is cool, but the 2 is fantastic in its own right.',kindle2,positive,0,0,0,0
```

It is comma seperated, and it has 7 fields. When I tried to read this file I got an error:

```
zz=  pd.read_csv('proc_data.csv', sep=',')
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 8 fields in line 14, saw 9
```

I guess it is complaning about the commas within the first column. (The part between `'` characters)

Is it possible to read this file correctly?

```
head -15 less proc_data.csv
head: less: No such file or directory
==> proc_data.csv <==
content,topic,class,NRC-Affect-Intensity-anger_Score,NRC-Affect-Intensity-fear_Score,NRC-Affect-Intensity-sadness_Score,NRC-Affect-Intensity-joy_Score
'@stellargirl I loooooooovvvvvveee my Kindle2. Not that the DX is cool, but the 2 is fantastic in its own right.',kindle2,positive,0,0,0,0
'Reading my kindle2...  Love it... Lee childs is good read.',kindle2,positive,0,0,0,1.375
'Ok, first assesment of the #kindle2 ...it fucking rocks!!!',kindle2,positive,0,0,0,0
'@kenburbary You\'ll love your Kindle2. I\'ve had mine for a few months and never looked back. The new big one is huge! No need for remorse! :)',kindle2,positive,0,0,0.594,1.125
'@mikefish  Fair enough. But i have the Kindle2 and I think it\'s perfect  :)',kindle2,positive,0,0,0,0.719
'@richardebaker no. it is too big. I\'m quite happy with the Kindle2.',kindle2,positive,0,0,0,0.788
'Fuck this economy. I hate aig and their non loan given asses.',aig,negative,0.828,0.484,0.656,0
'Jquery is my new best friend.',jquery,positive,0,0,0,0.471
'Loves twitter',twitter,positive,0,0,0,0
'how can you not love Obama? he makes jokes about himself.',obama,positive,0,0,0,0.828
'Check this video out -- President Obama at the White House Correspondents\' Dinner ',obama,neutral,0,0,0,0.109
'@Karoli I firmly believe that Obama/Pelosi have ZERO desire to be civil.  It\'s a charade and a slogan, but they want to destroy conservatism',obama,negative,0,0,0,0.484
'House Correspondents dinner was last night whoopi, barbara &amp; sherri went, Obama got a standing ovation',obama,positive,0,0,0.078,0
'Watchin Espn..Jus seen this new Nike Commerical with a Puppet Lebron..sh*t was hilarious...LMAO!!!',nike,positive,0,0,0,0.672
```

Comment: It looks like the CSV file was incorrectly created. If a proper CSV writer wasn't used to create the file, it's near impossible to know whether a comma is part of the string or a delimiter, so everything will just split on commas and give more columns than really exist.

Comment: @roganjosh why did you think in that way ?

Comment: If there's a comma in inside sentence, the sentence is wrapped with double quotes `"` not single quotes `'`. Edit your csv to change single quote to double quotes.

Comment: Can you post up to line 14 since that is where the error is happening? Or just add the the line before, line of, and line after the error?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad there is no bulletproof way of doing that once the CSV has already been created. If the OP doesn't make the original file, they may simply not be able to do it

Comment: @roganjosh I'm just talking about the row that he has shown. The row has that error, I don't know about rest of the file.

Comment: @jtweeder I posted first 15 lines. The csv file was not created by me

Comment: can you try the keyword `quotechar="'"`?

Comment: @Uvar, thanks for reply, I tried `qqq = pd.read_csv('proc_data.csv',quotechar="'")` and got the following error: `  Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 7 fields in line 13, saw 8`

Comment: `pd.read_clipboard(sep=',',quotechar="'", error_bad_lines=False, escapechar='\\')` exchange clipboard for csv here. Worst case scenario, your lines which it can't parse will get dropped (you'll still get a warning), but this should read in the data you've shown.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to separate the columns by commas, yet within strings commas can be present.

This would normally be taken care of by the `quoting` argument of the `read_csv` method, which defaults to `quoting='"'`. However, in your csv file, you have single quotes, so you need to change to `quoting="'"`.

This, however, runs into the issue that inside of the strings, apostrophes are present, which are preceded by escaping backslashes. By default, `pd.read_csv` has its `escapechar` argument set to `None`, so you'll have to set this one as well.

All in all, we end up with:

```
pd.read_csv('proc_data.csv', sep=',',quotechar="'", escapechar='\\')
```

Note that the `escapechar` itself needs to be escaped here.

If you're not that concerned about individual lines and just want to read in as much as you can succesfully parse, you can add in they keyword `error_bad_lines=False`. Then figure out from the warnings whether those lines can be fixed or need to be given up on.

Comment: I don't think that he should put `error_bad_lines=False`. By not putting it, he'll know whether the whole data is successfully read using this, or whether he needs to do something else too.

Comment: I agree to the sentiment; however, he/she'll still be alerted to there being lines which are unreadable (as warning_bad_lines still defaults to True), without breaking all of the code. As I reckon this is meant to be used in a rather large data processing format, I added it in to accommodate for unforeseen tweet-hell screwing everything up. Think I should just leave it as a note, but leave it out of the answer?

Comment: My opinion: Yes.